# How to loop the lines of a pipe in powershell one by one

Tags: powershell, loops, pipe

I'm trying to loop through the lines of a pipe one by one in with the following powershell code :

```
PS C:\> $a = "dir1
>> dir3"
PS C:\> echo $a | % { echo "=> line = "$_  }
=> line =
dir1
dir3
PS C:\>
```

I also tried this but I get the same result :

```
PS C:\> echo $a | Out-String -Stream | % { echo "=> line = "$_  }
=> line =
dir1
dir3
PS C:\>
```

I'm expecting this :

```
=> line = dir1
=> line = dir3
```

Answer (score 3):

`$a` is a single *multi-line* `string` in your example, if you want to enumerate each line first you would need to split it, either using [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.4) (a PowerShell regex based splitting operator) or [`.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-8.0) (a splitting method from the `string` class). As aside, `echo` (`Write-Output`), is not needed in this case.

```
$a = "dir1
dir3"

$a -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object { "=> line = " + $_  }

# Outputs:
# => line = dir1
# => line = dir3

$a.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine) | ForEach-Object { "=> line = " + $_  }

# Outputs:
# => line = dir1
# => line = dir3
```